# Creating groups in SQL as placeholders

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a dataset that is to display in a SSRS report.
This is the data:

```
Board   TicketGroup TicketType  TicketCnt
Support Closed      Closed      79
Support Closed      FCR         13
Support Open        Open        12
Support Submitted   Submitted   91
```

I want to display the data in a bar chart like this:
[image]

I am not sure if I can use the current query and configure the SSRS report to display groups like this.  But if I can create the query so that there are groups returned like this:

```
Board   TicketGroup TicketType  TicketCnt
    Support Closed      Closed      79
    Support Closed      FCR         13
    Support Closed      Open        0
    Support Closed      Submitted   0
    Support Open        Open        12
    Support Open        Closed      0
    Support Open        FCR         0
    Support Open        Submitted   0
    Support Submitted   Submitted   91
    Support Submitted   Open        0
    Support Submitted   Closed      0
    Support Submitted   FCR         0
```

With this data I can create a chart that does not show the 0 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a bunch of `cross join`s to produce all the combinations of board, ticket group and ticket type and then left join with it your table:

```
select b.board,
    g.ticketGroup,
    t.ticketType,
    coalesce(t2.ticketCnt, 0) as ticketCnt
from (
    select distinct board
    from your_table
    ) b
cross join (
    select distinct ticketGroup
    from your_table
    ) g
cross join (
    select distinct ticketType
    from your_table
    ) t
left join your_table t2 on b.board = t2.board
    and g.ticketGroup = t2.ticketGroup
    and t.ticketType = t2.ticketType;
```